# Проблемы с кодировкой в vs2015

Tags: кодировка, visual-studio-2015

Установил vs2015 update3 на Windows 10. Язык Windows 10 русский.

Теперь когда у меня появляется exception по ходу выполнения программы у меня вместо описания исключения абракадабра вместо кириллицы выводится. Сделал скрин, чтобы было проще понять проблему
https://i.stack.imgur.com/chOdi.png .

Подскажите, как можно решить эту проблему ? В идеале хотелось бы, чтобы выводились в бинарнике подробности исключения на английском. Смена VS2015 на английскую версию не решила проблемы.

Comment: *Пуск->Параметры->Язык и региональные параметры: вкладка Дополнительно* проверьте какой язык у Вас установлен для программ не поддерживающих юникод. у меня *кракозябры* были в консоли из за некорректно установленного языка

Comment: Был установлен Английский(США). Cейчас установил Русский и выводится описание исключения правильно. Также, по всей видимости, если нужно явно определить язык на котором выдается описание  исключения, то нужно это определить в коде http://stackoverflow.com/a/530338/6890462 .